# Using a unique_ptr as a private member in an abstract base class

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ (but not C or OOP) but I'm trying to do things the "right" way and avoid any bad and/or dangerous habits, so I'm using Google's C++ coding guidelines and Effective C++ as starting points for my learning.

I have an abstract base class with a `unique_ptr` as a member. If I make it private and only provide access to derived classes via a getter (per Google C++ style guidelines), is this the best way to do it? Or am I missing a potential pitfall here?

**Base.h:**

```
#include "Document.h"

typedef std::unique_ptr<Document> pDOC;

class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base() = 0;

    pDOC& GetDoc();

private:
    // Unique pointers cannot be shared, so don't allow copying
    Base(Base const &); // not supported
    Base &operator=(Base const &); // not supported
    pDOC m_doc;
};
```

**Base.cpp**

```
#include "base.h"

Base::Base()
: m_xmldoc(new Document) {}

// Class destructor (no need to delete m_doc since it is a smart pointer)
Base::~Base() {}

pDOC& Base::GetDoc() {
    return m_doc;
}
```

Comment: You are returning a reference with `GetDoc`, which means you can do anything you would be able to do with m_doc if it was not private, this is not bad since you probably want derived classes to change the m_doc, but this is not any safer than letting the derived classes change the pointer directly.

Comment: I would do `Document* GetDoc() const { return m_doc.get(); }`.  This is the "good" use of a plain pointer: something that might be null, but the using code doesn't need to worry about its ownership (as long as the `Base` is unmodified).

Comment: Don't follow Google's style guide. It's for Google's existing legacy code, not for new modern C++ code.

Comment: I'd recommend to use Google coding guide only if you work for Google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, call it `upDoc` instead of `pDOC` -- `unique_ptr` is sufficiently strange that you'd want some indication that the type isn't just a pointer.  (There is a strong tendency to define pointer types as starting with a lower-case p, so many people could be confused by your use).

Second, `GetDoc` if it is only intended for derived classes should be `protected` not `public`.

Third, I'd question fully exposing a reference to the `unique_ptr` to all children.  What is the responsibility of `Base`?  Does it manage the lifetime of the `m_doc`?  If so, expose a `Document*` instead of a `upDoc` (`return m_doc.get();` instead of `return m_doc;`)

If all `Base` does is hold an `m_doc` without managing its lifetime, then why does it exist?  It provides no public interface, and it provides little to no functionality.

Comment: If you expose a `Document*` then someone might be tempted to assign it to a `shared_ptr`. I think the reference is appropriate in this case.

Comment: Good point about making `GetDoc()` protected. The full `Base` class actually has some public member functions that operate on the `Document`, and it does manage its lifetime.

Comment: @MarkRansom anyone who takes a `Document*` that they don't own, and passes it to a `shared_ptr`, is going to get what they deserve.  Regardless of how the `Document*` is managed (`unique_ptr`, in dtor, or whatever), it is never, ever valid to pass a `Document*` you do not own -- that you did not just create -- to a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @jasonm76 Then `Document* GetDoc() { return m_doc.get(); }` is the right interface.  Returning a `unique_ptr<Document>&` means you are saying "you can take over control over the ownership of this `Document`, in fact you are supposed to whenever you want!"

Answer (score 0):

> If I make it private and only provide access to derived classes via a getter

Then you are doing extra typing to get the same effect as offering a public/protected member directly. Admittedly, you can add code to accessors and you can set breakpoints, but that does not change the fact that you are breaking encapsulation by providing direct access to your internals.

Said differently, there is nothing that inhibits users of the type from doing `obj.GetDoc().release()` and breaking the invariants you might have for your type.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to expose a reference to the object managed by `std::unique_ptr`, for example:

```
    const Document& getDocument() const { return *m_doc; }
    Document& getMutableDocument() { return *m_doc; }
```

This is suggested by Jonas Devlieghere [here](https://jonasdevlieghere.com/containers-of-unique-pointers/) as a possible approach to expose "containers of unique pointers", as he argues that "*[b]y returning references rather than pointers, you make it clear that the caller is not responsible for managing [the pointed object]'s lifetime.*"